# How do I handle documents where a property has been stored as different types

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I use c# models to map to my mongo documents. One of the model properties is

```
 public List<string> genres = new List<string>();
```

This maps most of the time as the document stores genres in the following way...

```
"genres" : [ 
    "rock", 
    "rockabilly", 
    "punk"
]
```

At some point however, genres were being stores as a plain array (no square brackets)...

```
"genres" : {
    "1" : "rock"
}
```

This causes the Driver to throw an exception...

```
Expected element name to be '_t', not '1'
```

What is the best way to handle this?
Can I adapt the document style before it gets to the Model?
Can I treat it as null and then override it when updating?
Should I just clean up my data and make it all consistent?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plain array, it's an embedded document and the driver doesn't know of which type. You should definitely clean up your data and make it consistent.

If you can't, the next best thing is to create a different data structure matching the old format and use it to convert to the new one.

Comment: Sorry yes the first example is an array the second is an embedded document. Not sure what you mean by 'create a different data structure...' Do you mean create a new property and run a routine to convert the old mixed type genres into the new consistent one and then just use that?

Comment: @user2473827 Yes, either that, or a new class with all the same properties and the old version of the genres property